# Using algorithm whether it infringe patents?

Tags: software

I am planning to develop my own algorithm and software solution that will use Least Significant Bit Algorithm (LSB) in digital watermarking.

I have seen that there are lot of articles regarding this topic as well as there are lot of patents issued on this topic and using this algorithm LSB.

My question is, if I develop a solution, can I be infringing any of those patents? Or is LSB public algorithm and everyone can use it?

Comment: I fear your question may not be answerable here. Whether you infringe a patent depends on whether your solution would infringe a claim of that patent. It therefore depends entirely on what your solution involves, and therefore may be a better question for an attorney to work on with you.

Comment: @Maca. This is the best answer, you should post it as such.

Answer (score -1):

LSB is public algorithm and everyone can use it.
Such algorithm has been published at almost every book. You can implement LSB yourself by referencing to published books free. Or use python lib scipy, numpy free.

But, if you find some  LSB optimization algorithm patent, you cannot refer to such patent. Because the patented LSB optimization algorithm is protected by patent.

Comment: I'm afraid this might be a bit misleading in its current form. Just because something is well known doesn't mean it is free to use in a given application. That is, it may be the case that the algorithm itself is so old that it could not be under patent now. But it is impossible to say that its use in digital watermarking has not been patented more recently.